# easy exponential population growth problem help?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function

The question is: Let $C(t)$ be the number of cougars on an island at time t years (where $t > 0$). The number of cougars is increasing at a rate directly proportional to $3500 * C(t)$. Also, $C(0) = 1000$, and $C(5) = 2000$.

a. Find C(t) as a function of t only.

I started with $dC/dt = 3500C$. Solving that gives $C = Ae^{3500t}$. Is this all wrong?

There's another part: c. Find the limit as $t$ tends to infinity of $C(t)$ , and explain its meaning.

any help would, well, help! thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost right. You should start with

$$\frac{dC}{dt}=3500kC$$

since it says "directly proportional to". Then your answer should contain this $k$ and the other constant $A$ which is the initial condition. Then use the other given condition, you can find $k$.

Use this equation, you can find the limit when $t\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: If I start with dC/dt = 3500kC, and separate the C's and t's, and then integrate, I get: ln (C) = 3500kt + 3500kz, (where z is a constant of integration). Could I just assume the whole 3500kz term to be a constant? and if I do (say make 3500kz = 'u'), then if I exponentiate both sides, I end up with: C = e^(3500*k*t) * e^u. Then would e^u be A, the initial condition? I feel like this is wrong because I have never ended up with an expression like C = Ae^(3500*k*t). Is this correct so far? I greatly appreciate the help if you made it this far!

Comment: @TheOneWhoCould: Yes, that is totally correct. Since they are all constants, multiplying, or exponentiating (not sure about the word, but you know what I mean) still gives you arbitrary constants. So you can use one $A$ as your constants. Now if you plug $0$ into $t$ and $1000$ into $C$, you can see $A$ is exactly the initial population.

Comment: Thank you so much! Just one little problem: To find 'k', I do (2000) = (1000) * e^(3500*k*(5)). This yields 2 = e^(17500k). Now if I take ln() of both sides, I get ln(2) = 17500k, which I am almost positive is not going to give me the right value for k (since it's just too small!). So where am I going wrong in my calculations?                                                                EDIT: I plugged the equation into wolfram alpha to find k, and got the same value i.e. ln(2)/17500. How could that possibly be correct? Isn't k usually a normal looking value, like 0.3, or 0.8?

Comment: So I carried on, and plugging ln(2)/17500 into the equation for 'k' gave me: C = 1000e^(0.14*t). A much more soothing figure, haha. So, to find the limit of C(t) as t -> infinity, I just plug in infinity into t, right? So e^(0.14* infinity). That would end up going to infinity...?

Comment: @TheOneWhoCould: Right. The $3500$ makes it smaller :) And yes, it should go to infinity.